# VLOOKUP random distinct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with age groups

```
|  nr |  age_from  |  age_to  |
|  1  |    35      |    37    |
|  2  |    36      |    40    |
```

and a the second table (second_table) with person_age and person_id.

```
|  person_age |  person_id  |
|  35         |  22334455   |
|  39         |  66778899   |
|  39         |  123456789  |
|  39         |  222456222  |
```

I need to find random 3 person_id's for the first table that fit this age group, for example:

```
|  nr |  age_from  |  age_to  | person_id1 | person_id2 |  Person_id3   
|  1  |    35      |    37    | 22334455 
|  2  |    36      |    40    | 123456789  | 66778899 (not the same as the first!!!)  | 222456222
```

Person_id must be must be unique, but VLOOKUP finds only the first matching row. It turns out 3 identical person_id's.

My excel function:

```
=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(A2:B2);second_table!A:B;2;FALSE)
```

But it returns identical persons, because finds the first.

Comment: Your formula structure is not "asking the question" you think it's asking.  It says "pick a random age between 36 and 40, and then use that age as the lookup value."  A lookup will always stop at the first value that meets the lookup criteria.  What you are actually trying to do is "Select all of the values form second_table that fall between 36 and 40, and select a random one of those."  That is complicated without Excel O365.  But even more complicated is preventing a random value from being reused.  Without the use of helper columns you are going to end up with a profoundly complex formula.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying:

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=LET(x,A2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(A:A)),z,IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,LET(y,FILTER(DROP(TOCOL(F:F,1),1)&"",(DROP(TOCOL(E:E,1),1)>=INDEX(x,b,2))*(DROP(TOCOL(E:E,1),1)<=INDEX(x,b,3)),""),TOROW(SORTBY(y,RANDARRAY(ROWS(y)))))))),1),""),HSTACK(VSTACK(A1:C1,x),VSTACK("person_id"&SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(z)),z)))
```

This will include more columns if need be:

[image]

**Note:** If a person's age falls in multiple categories his/her ID number will reflect in all of these categories too.

Comment: Thank you, but I have not LET() function

Answer (score 0):

[image: Result]

- First result:

If your excel supports Filter, then you can use this formula. Instead of TOROW, you can also use Transpose function.

=TOROW(FILTER($F$2:$F$12,($E$2:$E$12>=I4)*($E$2:$E$12<=J4)))

- Second result:

=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$12,SMALL(IF(($E$2:$E$12>=$I12)*($E$2:$E$12<=$J12),ROW($F$2:$F$12)-ROW($F$1)),COLUMNS($K12:K12))),"")

Hope it clears..

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution **assuming** you can use `TEXTSPLIT` function. You can try the following formula in `G2` cell:

```
=LET(ages, A2:A5, mapR, MAP(D2:D3, E2:E3, F2:F3, LAMBDA(nr, from,to, 
  LET(set, FILTER(B2:B5, (ages >= from) * (ages <= to),0), 
    n, IF(@set=0,0, ROWS(set)), m, MIN(n,nr), IF(n=0, "", 
    TEXTJOIN(",",,INDEX(set, SORTBY(SEQUENCE(m),RANDARRAY(m,,1,n,TRUE)))))))),
  IFERROR(1*TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",, mapR),",",";", TRUE),""))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

### Explanation

We use `MAP` function to calculate the main result (`mapR`). On each row of `mapR` will be the ids values randomly selected concatenated by `,`. `FILTER` function is used to match the search criteria **Age from**, **Age To** columns. We prevent the case no result was found, where `set` is the output of `FILTER`, adding the third input argument to `FILTER` (`0`, assuming no value from **Person Id** column has such value) and then to calculate the number of rows returned (`n`) via the following condition:

```
IF(@set=0,0, ROWS(set))
```

So when `n` is zero, an empty string is returned.

Then we need also to prevent the situation where the number of rows of `set` is lower than the numbers of rows required by `nr` on each iteration of `MAP`, via the following condition for `m` `MIN(n,nr)`.

The condition to generate the random numbers is the following:

```
SORTBY(SEQUENCE(m),RANDARRAY(m,,1,n,TRUE))
```

it ensures no duplicated random numbers are generated. The output of previous result is used on `INDEX` function to select the rows from the `FILTER` result (`set`).

The last step generates the output array via `TEXTSPLIT` using the output of `MAP` function (`mapR`). We multiply the output of `TEXTSPLIT` by `1`, to convert the result to a numeric value. Finally, `IFERROR` is used to replace `#N/A` with an empty string when the number of columns returned on a given rows is less than the maximum number of columns returned.

If the result can be returned in a string format, then you can replace the `IFERROR` call with:

```
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",, mapR),",",";", TRUE,,"")
```

Using `pad_with` input argument from `TEXTSPLIT` function.